# Excel email validation for position of . after @ character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In addition to checking if a cell has an @ and a . character associated to it, is there any way we can take the following and check if there is atleast one . is after the @ character? and if not, that consider the email address false?

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("@",C2))),NOT(ISERROR(FIND(".",C2))),ISERROR(FIND(" ",C2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works and is very easy to understand and provides better email validation:

`=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(".",A8,SEARCH("@",A8)+2)),"FAILS","PASSES")`

Comment: @Blackhawk, no problem.  I use this formula very often.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",MID(C2,FIND("@",C2),LEN(C2)))),FALSE,TRUE)
```

The email address must contain both '@' and '.' anyway so you shouldn't need to test that separately so just go straight to checking that a '.' exists after an '@' in the cell and return TRUE if it does, else return FALSE for any other scenario.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one as well keeping your original formula statements:

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("@",C2))),(LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"@",REPT(" ",LEN(C2))),LEN(C2))))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"@",REPT(" ",LEN(C2))),LEN(C2))),".",""))>=1),ISERROR(FIND(" ",C2)))
```

it worked for me.

Comment: This fails if there are 2 dots in front of the @

Comment: @blackhawk i had misunderstood your condition. It is now corrected, you can try it.

Comment: Thanks for the adjustment